# How to create a program which will Create Table and modify data in Oracle Database in Java and have multiple usage

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, create-table

It is as the title suggest. I want to create a java program in which I will be able to create tables and modify data using Oracle Base/JDBC and I want it to have multiple usage. Sadly when I google "oracle create table", there are only programs which are useless after one usage.

For now I tried something like that, but it is not working as program says the table does not exist.

```
try{
    boolean tableExists;
    Statement statement = createStatement();
    String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM tableName";

    While(statement.execute(sql1)){
        tableExists = true;
        break;
    }

    while(tableExists= false){
        String sql2 = "CREATE TABLE tableName(id integer not null, name char(10) not null)";
        statement.execute(sql2);
        tableExists = true;
        break;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Looks like your logic is incorrect  while(tableExists= false)

Comment: you are better off using built-in jdbc metadata functions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780284/how-to-get-all-table-names-from-a-database

Comment: What value does `tableExists` have when it is declared?

Comment: First you initialize your variable `boolean tableExists = false`

 And change your
 `while(!tableExists) {
your logic here ...
}`

Answer (score 0):

First , you are unnecessary using `while` statements, its basically a case of `if`.

Secondly, your code has Java syntax level problems like statement , `while(tableExists= false)` so it seems you are new to Java too.

Thirdly, if table doesn't exist , your first call `statement.execute(sql1)` will throw an `Exception` and control will directly go to catch block & your second statement will not be executed. So I would revise your code to something like below.

Also, note that second query needs to be `executeUpdate` & not `execute`  ...Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10624686/3850730)

```
try{
    boolean tableExists = false;
    Statement statement = createStatement();
    String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM tableName";
    if(statement.execute(sql1)){
        tableExists = true;
    }

    // do other things 

    return ;

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    if(!tableExists){
        String sql2 = "CREATE TABLE tableName(id integer not null, name char(10) not null)";
        statement.executeUpdate(sql2);
        tableExists = true;
    }
    return;
}
```

Note that this is still not a very good & fool proof code since control can go to catch block for other errors too & not only table exist issue.Table not existing is one of many reasons that an exception can be thrown & you might need to examine trace message to exactly know if table not existing is the real issue or can use something like `EXISTS` in SQL to try creating table only if it doesn't exist.